# Is "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta" still actual / up to date?

Tags: support, beta-sites

Is [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) still actual / up to date?

In particular, are the points about the elevator pitch, and the site design still necessary to discuss in a site in beta phase?
So far, I have not seen any site using an elevator pitch; *English Language & Usage* has a blog, but I don't see any elevator pitch in the blog, nor in the main site. The design is decided when the site is going to graduate, and the designer who works in that already open a question on the meta site to show a preview of how the site will appear; the same question is normally used to point out things that would need to be changed, or that could be changed.

Comment: The elevator pitch is at least in part an attempt to get the site to figure out its focus. If you can't summarize your focus and appeal in a focused pitch, maybe the site is a bit too broad and/or doesn't quite know what's on or off topic.

Comment: I agree with the "elevator pitch" question generally. If you can't describe your proposed site in a limited amount of time, then should it really be considered? This seems like a valid filter for sites that have no purpose or future. You should know how to persuade someone to look at your site before bothering the SE team with the request to consider it. Or did I miss the point?

Comment: I don't see the reason of the −1: I am not saying the elevator pitch point should be removed; I am asking if what reported in that article is still updated. @AnnaLear I am not sure I am understanding how can the elevator pitch help with a site's focus, when the site is described to be a site, "for project managers, themers, developers, site-builders, administrators, and businesses using or thinking about using the Drupal CMS."

Comment: The list is fairly outdated. [This is an attempt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/200868) at a more current and dynamic list.