# Either fix edit preview display to render bare links to more than five sites just like the post renderer, or convert all links

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-review, hyperlinks, internal-links

This is probably easier to show than tell...

On the recent question [Is asking for user stories off-topic on meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301348/is-asking-for-user-stories-off-topic-on-meta-sites), I see the following:

[image: View of question directly]

As you can see, the first five links render properly, but after that, they stop converting.

Unfortunately, this isn't obvious to the person writing the post, which I discovered when I went to edit the post to fix the "broken" links. In the edit window, it renders all of the links just fine:

[image: View of question edit window (all links are converted)]

I understand that this behavior is expected based on balpha's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/284336):

> 1. Links to questions on the same site are unlimited.
> 2. Links to other sites are limited to
>
>    - a) 5 linked-to sites and
>    - b) N questions per target site, where N is 200 on meta sites and 10 on non-metas (this is about the site that the post containing the link is posted on, *not* the site that is being linked to)

So if this rule is still going to stay in effect, please fix the edit view to also not automatically convert more than five linked-to sites to help people writing posts know that they need to manually title the links to the other questions.

That said, I'd *prefer* that (at least on MSE) this limitation be removed or raised. Even in the answer, balpha says:

> The restrictions are *currently* as follows, but note that they do look a bit contrived, resulting from the fact that they have grown over time (from single site to cross-site, from "there are no subsites" to "facebook.SO", etc.), so it's not unlikely that we'll revisit them.

So, if it's not hurting performance, can we please increase the limit or remove it?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this is a feature request or a bug.

Comment: The last 4 links are naked again... if that's the correct term

Comment: Given that you're now an employee, is it possible that you can re-raise this issue internally?

Comment: If staff can't get a staff response for their own old questions, what chance do the rest of us have? ;)

Comment: @V2Blast If staff can't get a staff response to their own old comments, what chance do the rest of us have? ;)